# Odoo Rounding error - thousand separator

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

I've rounding on account entries 0

Display in Spanish language is set to: [3,0], Decimal separator ",", thousand separator "."

Rounding factor on the Money (CLP): 1.000000, computational accuracy: 4

During Editing

[image: During Editing]

After Editing

[image: During Editing]

417.311 reduces to 417

I try to find the bug in view_list.js and view_list_editable.js, but I cant found

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that field is a Float type and not integer.

Answer (score 0):

Check the field type as well as use decimal precision for your field